# I keep getting this error message and I don't know why

Tags: c#

Error message is:

> '_djv.Authenticator' does not contain a definition for 'authenticate'
>   and no extension method 'authenticate' accepting a first argument of
>   type '_djv.Authenticator' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)  my code is below, I have a
>   console app program and a class called authenticator, both pieces of
>   code are down there.

```
namespace _Authenticator 
{
    public class Authenticator 
    {
        private Dictionary < string, string > dictionary = new Dictionary < string, string > ();

        public Authenticator() 
        {
            dictionary.Add("username1", "password1");
            dictionary.Add("username2", "password2");
            dictionary.Add("username3", "password3");
            dictionary.Add("username4", "password4");
            dictionary.Add("username5", "password5");
        }

        public bool authenticate(string username, string password) 
        {
            bool authenticated = false;

            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(username) && dictionary[username] == password) 
            {
                authenticated = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                authenticated = false;
            }

            return authenticated;
        }
    }
}

using _Authenticator;

namespace _djv 
{
    class Authenticator 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
            var username = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
            var password = Console.ReadLine();

            var auth = new Authenticator();

            if (auth.authenticate(username, password)) 
                Console.WriteLine("Valid username/password combination");
            else 
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/password combination");

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of your classes are named `Authenticator`. When you call `new Authenticator` you're actually creating an instance of the class that the code is running in, which doesn't have an `authenticate` method.

Comment: You have two classes with the same name Authenticator. Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: You must have deleted your earlier question. You were already told in no uncertain terms that having your classes/namespaces set up this way is extremely poor code. It is confusing, and leads to easily avoidable mistakes like this. Your `Authenticator` in `_djv` should NOT be called `Authenticator` because it **is not an Authenticator**. A better name would be something like `AuthenticatorTester` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a clash of class names. Your `auth` variable refers to the class inside `_djv` namespace. Specify the full name of the class to be able to use it.

```
var auth = new _Authenticator.Authenticator();
```

Alternatively, you can create an alias for the class. I'd recommend this approach here as it makes writing code less tedious.

```
using Auth = _Authenticator.Authenticator;
(...)
var auth = new Auth();
```

Actually, I think the best idea would be to rename one of the classes. Everything will get a lot cleaner and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes called `Authenticator`. If you don't specify the namespace explicitly, the class in the current namespace will be used (which is the wrong one in this case).

You can solve it either by:

1. Explicitly create an instance of the right class

   `var auth = new _Authenticator.Authenticator()`
2. Rename your main class to something else, `Main`, for instance.

I would strongly recommend option 2, to prevent further confusion.